Saving Screenshot with an assigned name in a Series
I have been looking for a few days and I cannot find an example of assigning a String name to a series of screenshots so I can recall the screenshots from memory using the base name + 1,2,3 etc. assigned to the screenshot when it is saved.
Taking and saving the screenshot is well documented, as is opening the OutputStream with a .jpg or .png incremental name. I have been looking for the line of code to link the name the OutputStream is opened with to the name the screenshot object is created with.
I realize I will have to close the OutputStream and reopen it with the incremented name as I make my changes to the screen and then take the new screenshot.
As I look at the CameraDemo on GitHub it looks to be implied that the camera shot is saved as the OutputStream name because I do not see a link between the capture and the save. I can't determine if that is the case.
To reopen the screenshots I will recover the screenshot group base name from a Text file and then recover the screenshots in the order they were saved to play in the ImageViewer. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Do you mean this?
public String getCurrentName() {
    return "Screenshot-" + Preferences.get("screenshot-number", 1);
}

public String getNextName() {
    int next = Preferences.get("screenshot-number", 1) + 1;
    Preferences.set("screenshot-number", next);
    return "Screenshot-" + next;
}


Thanks for your reply. An example: I am naming a play, and will move the players and ball around the field. A Text Box gets the play name, in this case 4Square. I can use the method above to number the screenshots, but I have not found an example of taking the String entry from the Text Box, assigning that string to name the screenshot, creating the OutputStream using that string+1+.jpg to save the picture to FileSystemStorage, then incrementing the name, taking another screenshot after everything is moved, creating new OutputStream for pic 2, and repeat through the end of the play. Thanks.

I suggest you use Storage which is simpler than FileSystemStorage you just open an output stream to the storage and pass it to ImageIO when generating the screenshot image.
